# Warning: shadow a member of this

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Tengo el siguiente problema. Necesito quitar todos los warnings de un fuente y hay uno (que lo tengo en varios fuentes) que dice lo siguiente, estoy usando linux y cmake:

```
/mnt/clas/Source/CLAS/lashandle.h: In constructor ‘LAS_HeaderSectionValue::LAS_HeaderSectionValue(const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&)’:
/mnt/clas/Source/CLAS/lashandle.h:63: warning: declaration of ‘Description’ shadows a member of 'this'
/mnt/clas/Source/CLAS/lashandle.h:63: warning: declaration of ‘Value’ shadows a member of 'this'
/mnt/clas/Source/CLAS/lashandle.h:63: warning: declaration of ‘MesUnit’ shadows a member of 'this'
/mnt/clas/Source/CLAS/lashandle.h:63: warning: declaration of ‘ShortName’ shadows a member of 'this'
```

el archivo .h donde me indica la linea tiene la siguiente declaracion/definicion:

```
class LAS_HeaderSectionValue
{
public:
    LAS_HeaderSectionValue(const QString &ShortName, const QString &MesUnit, const QString &Value, const QString &Description)
    {
        this->m_pShortName = new QString(ShortName);
        this->m_pMesUnit = new QString(MesUnit);
        this->m_pValue = new QString(Value);
        this->m_pDescription = new QString(Description);
    }
};
```

Alguien me puede ayudar/guiar para quitar ese warning?. No termino de entender que es lo que sucede. Mi código no tenia los this pero yo se los agregué y aun asi sigue indicando el mismo warning

Comment: El código de error es bastante auto-explicativo si entiendes inglés. Hay miembros del objeto `LAS_HeaderSectionValue` que se llama exactamente igual que alguno de los parámetros pasados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás omitiendo información importante sobre la clase. Presupongo que tu clase se parece más a esto:

```
class LAS_HeaderSectionValue
{
public:
    LAS_HeaderSectionValue(const QString &ShortName, const QString &MesUnit, const QString &Value, const QString &Description);

    QString ShortName();
    QString MesUnit();
    QString Value();
    // ...
};
```

El error básicamente te está diciendo que las variables locales del constructor tienen el mismo nombre que miembros de la clase lo que está provocando un ocultamiento de estos últimos.

La solución es tan sencilla como cambiar el nombre a las variables del constructor:

```
LAS_HeaderSectionValue(const QString &shortName, const QString &mesUnit, const QString &value, const QString &description);
```

**BONUS TRACK**

No tiene demasiado sentido que los miembros `m_pShortName` y compañía sean punteros. La propia clase `QString` se encarga de garantizar el ciclo de vida de la cadena que almacena. Vas a conseguir un código más limpio, rápido y manejable si usas `QString` por valor:

```
class LAS_HeaderSectionValue
{
    QString m_ShortName;
    QString m_MesUnit;
    QString m_Value;
    QString m_Description;

public:

    LAS_HeaderSectionValue(const QString &shortName, const QString &mesUnit, const QString &value, const QString &description)
    {
        m_ShortName = shortName;
        m_MesUnit = mesUnit;
        m_Value = value;
        m_Description = description;
    }
};
```

O mejor aún:

```
LAS_HeaderSectionValue(const QString &shortName, const QString &mesUnit, const QString &value, const QString &description)
  : m_ShortName(shortName),
    m_MesUnit(mesUnit),
    m_Value(value),
    m_Description(description)
{ }
```